# Disable Specific Keys in IE 6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, kiosk

I need to disable specific keys (Ctrl and Backspace) in Internet Explorer 6.  Is there a registry hack to do this.  It has to be IE6.  Thanks.

Long Edit:

@apandit: Whoops.  I need to more specific about the backspace thing.  When I say disable backspace, I mean disable the ability for Backspace to mimic the Back browser button.  In IE, pressing Backspace when the focus is not in a text entry field is equivalent to pressing Back (browsing to the previous page).

As for the Ctrl key.  There are some pages which have links which create new IE windows.  I have the popup blocker turned on, which block this.  But, Ctrl clicking result in the new window being launched.

This is for a kiosk application, which is currently a web based application.  Clients do not have the funds at this time to make their site kiosk friendly.  Things like URL filtering and disabling the URL entry field is already done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what purpose do you need this? Because disabling the backspace would be hell for typing urls or emails, etc.

We could recommend other workarounds if we knew the problem better.

EDIT 1:
This website seems to have some information as to how it's done. I can't verify it currently, but I'll look into it:
http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/disable-key-and-back-t44867.html

Edit 2:
This website has some key codes:
http://www.advscheduler.com/docs/manual/type_sendkeys.html
It seems BACKSPACE is 08.

EDIT 3: 
Found some more code for blocking, check this out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var sType = "keypress";</script> 

<!--[if IE]> 
<script type="text/javascript">sType = "keydown";</script> 
<![endif]--> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
fIntercept = function(e) { 
   // alert(e.keyCode);
  e = e || event.e; 
  if (e.keyCode == 116) { 
   // When F5 is pressed 
   fCancel(e); 
  } else if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 0 || e.keyCode == 82)) { 
   // When ctrl is pressed with R 
   fCancel(e); 
  } 
}; 

fCancel = function(e) { 
  if (e.preventDefault) { 
   e.stopPropagation(); 
   e.preventDefault(); 
  } else { 
   e.keyCode = 0; 
   e.returnValue = false; 
   e.cancelBubble = true; 
  } 
  return false; 
}; 

fAddEvent = function(obj, type, fn) { 
  if (obj.addEventListener) { 
   obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false); 
  } else { 
   obj['e'+type+fn] = fn; 
   obj[type+fn] = function() { 
    obj['e'+type+fn](window.event); 
   } 
   obj.attachEvent('on'+type, obj[type+fn]); 
  } 
}; 


fAddEvent(document, sType, fIntercept); 
</script>
```

Ok, now you should have all you need to do it. To disable backspace, the keycode is 08. You can probably just use the code I posted with slight modifications only... :\

Try it out and see if it's what you needed. (I hope you know how to use Javascript.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from a web page.  One of the main purposes of a web browser is to protect users from the internet.  They define a very specific set of things that web sites can do, and disabling buttons isn't in the list.

On the other hand, if you're a network admin and just want to mess with your users, you might be able to do it via some desktop software.  But I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: Since the question mentions a 'registry hack', I don't think @A Salim is looking for a way to do this from a web page.

Comment: Nevermind.  After reading the asker's clarification, I guess it was for a web application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this jQuery solution (tested on ie6 and firefox 3.6):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var tag = e.target.tagName;
    var ro = e.target.readOnly;
    var type = e.target.type;
    var tags = {
        INPUT : '',
        TEXTAREA : ''
    };
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {// backspace
        if (!(tag in tags && !ro && /text/.test(type))) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

hope it helps someone